# Background app stops working when using other apps

Tags: android, http, events, event-handling

I have an application that when started, it establishes a **long-live** http connection to a *restful stream api* in order to handle an event.

the application works perfectly fine when leaving the phone as is, without touching it.

But when using other applications while the app is working in the background, it suddenly stops working. (i'm guessing the http connection gets disconnected)

These are the permissions i have for the application:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: are you using Services https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: @GreenRobo I haven't implemented a service, but i'm thinking of.

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing that Your app may be killed by the system so it can reclaim memory to use on other processes since you are not posting any code. see this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/process-lifecycle.html) for more infomation.

Comment: Any ways to avoid this without writing a service?

Comment: I cant think of any other ways. Unless your app is running on foreground, which you don't want to. where are you running your work on btw?  onCreate ?

Comment: I create the objects in the onCreate and start the work in a button event handler. then the work runs in a event handler.

Comment: well since you want your app to run in background then you should put your work in a service. Even service may be killed by the system if it runs to long.
    A service process is one holding a Service that has been started with the startService() method. Though these processes are not directly visible to the user, they are generally doing things that the user cares about (such as background network data upload or download), so the system will always keep such processes running unless there is not enough memory to retain all foreground and visible processes.

Comment: Is it possible to put only the event handler in the service or do i need to put all the logic in it (such as start stream)?

Comment: you should put all logic in it. and when job done, dont forget to stop the service. you can call `stopSelf()` in the service

Comment: Can you help me over TeamViewer?

Comment: im afraid i cant help you with that. just put  the entire handler into service class, then call start handler,then startService() in your activity. google some tutorials about how to create a Service.

Comment: Is it possible to a service get stopped also?

Comment: sure, call `stopService(intent)` in your Activity, or `stopSelf()` in your service, use either one of them you see fit

Comment: I meant stopped by the os

Comment: will be stop by the os if it does not have enough memory to use. Im not sure my self since im only a apprentice, you should read more documents, including (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)
Sorry :), you should create another disscusion about this